# Função para totalizar valores de input selecionados em checkbox

Tags: php, javascript

Boa tarde.

Tenho uma table na minha página com colunas de quantidade e valor do produto. Esses valores são retornados do meu BD, em cada linha tem um checkbox para seleção, já fiz uma função para calcular o total de cada produto (quantidade * valor). O que preciso é uma função para totalizar a soma dos produtos selecionados pelo checkbox.

HTML/PHP

```html
<table id="produtos" class="table table-striped table-condensed table-bordered  table-hover">

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:10%">Produto</th>
      <th style="width:30%">Descricao</th>
      <th>Quantidade</th>
      <th>Valor Tabela</th>
      <th>Ultima Compra</th>
      <th style="width:5%">Emb.</th>
      <th style="width:5%">Peso Bruto</th>
      <th style="width:5%">Est. Casa</th>
      <th style="width:10%">Est. Cliente</th>
      <th style="width:10%">Qtd. Pedido</th>
      <th style="width:10%">Valor compra</th>
      <th style="width:20%">Total</th>
      <th>Sel.</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php $i = 0; 
      do {  ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row_vendas['produto']; ?><input type="hidden" name="produto[]" value="<?php echo $row_vendas['id_produto'] ?>"></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_vendas['descricao']; ?><input type="hidden" name="descricao[]" value="<?php echo $row_vendas['descricao'] ?>"></td>
      <td><?php echo number_format($row_vendas['quantidade'],3,',','.'); ?></td>
      <td><?php echo number_format($row_vendas['preco1'],2,',','.'); ?></td>
      <td><?php echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row_vendas['ultima_compra'])); ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_vendas['embalagem']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_vendas['peso_bruto']; ?><input type="hidden" name="peso[]" value="<?php echo $row_vendas['peso_bruto'] ?>"></td>
      <td><?php echo number_format($row_vendas['estoque'],3,',','.'); ?></td>
      <td><input type="number" min="1" name="estoque" style="width:80%" autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td><input type="number" min="1" name="qtd[]" id="qtd<?php echo $i ?>" style="width:80%" autocomplete="off" onChange="somaProduto(<?php echo $i; ?>)"></td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="valor[]" id="preco<?php echo $i; ?>" style="width:70%" value="<?php echo number_format($row_vendas['valor'],2,',','.') ?>" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return SomenteNumero(this, event);" onChange="somaProduto(<?php echo $i; ?>)">
      <input type="hidden" id="tolerancia<?php echo $i; ?>" style="width:80%" value="<?php echo $row_vendas['tolerancia_preco'] ?>" autocomplete="off">
      <input type="hidden" id="valTabela<?php echo $i; ?>" style="width:80%" value="<?php echo $row_vendas['preco1'] ?>" autocomplete="off">
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="totalProduto" disabled class="disabled" id="totalProduto<?php echo $i?>" style="width:80%" autocomplete="off"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" onClick="SomaTotais(<?php echo $i; ?>)" name="selecao[]" id="selecao<?php echo $i?>" value="<?php echo $i; ?>" style="width: 30px; height: 30px;"></td>              
  </tr>
  <?php $i = $i+1; } while ($row_vendas = mysql_fetch_assoc($vendas));?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript

```js
function somaProduto(nro){
    var qtd = $('#qtd'+nro+'').val();
    var valUnit = DesFormataMoeda($('#preco'+nro).val());

    total   = qtd * valUnit;

    $('#totalProduto'+nro+'').val(ConverteMoeda(total));
}
```

Fiz esta função, mas ainda não esta somando os valores:

```js
function SomaTotais(nro){
    var total = 0;
    $("input:checkbox[data-id=selecao]:checked").each(function () {
            var i = this.value;
            var valor = DesFormataMoeda($('#totalProduto'+i).val());                    
            total += valor              
        });
        alert(ConverteMoeda(total));

}
```

Comment: Poste o seu código html ai, para sabermos como esta  a sua estrutura e podermos lhe ajudar com o código.

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow PT, para que seja mais fácil te ajudatem inclua na sua pergunta o código HTML da tabela, e as funções que já estão funcionando

Comment: Apenas complementando o que @Sanção disse, recomendo ler, [Como fazer uma boa pergunta?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Reverti sua edição do título porque aqui não usamos esse espaço para marcar que a pergunta foi resolvida. Ver [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1078) (você vai precisar esperar um prazo do sistema antes de poder marcar sua própria resposta como aceita).

Comment: ok obrigado @bfavaretto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvido aqui, alterei função e funcionou como queria.

```js
function SomaTotais(){
 var total = 0;
 $("input:checkbox[data-id=selecao]:checked").each(function () {
  var i = this.value;
        var valor = Number(DesFormataMoeda($('#totalProduto'+i).val()));      
  total += valor;
  $('#total').html(total);    
 });   
}
```